# photo in the diva which is a triangle in the corner of the page

Tags: html, css, image

How can I make my photo be on the same level as div and overlap a bit?

```
<div id='triangle-topleft'>
   <img id="photo" src="photo.png">
</div>
```

```
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 350px solid #66CCFF;
    border-right: 350px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}
#photo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    float: left;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/KubaPilat/hyd5mcLx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add rule `transform: translateY()` to `#photo`.

Also, change `position: absolute` to `position: relative` to `#triangle-topleft`.

```css
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 350px solid #66CCFF;
    border-right: 350px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
}

#photo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    float: left;
    transform: translateY(-30%);
}
```

```html
<div id='triangle-topleft'>
   <img id="photo" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/2000885/1902/i/600/depositphotos_19021343-stock-photo-red-heart.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need that in #photo:
`top: -350px;`